# Qt: Get width of QTreeWidget as if no scrollbar was shown

Tags: qt, qt5, scrollbar

So I have a `QTreeWidget` that I populate with a bunch of items. While decreasing the widget's width, it will eventually start showing a horizontal scrollbar.

For layout purposes, I need to determine the width of my tree widget, but I need to get the width as if no scrollbar was shown. With that I mean that I don't want the width of the scroll area but the width of the contained widget (the actual list) that does not get fully shown but to whose edges I can scroll with the scrollbar. In other words: For the width calculation I would like to pretend as if the inner widget was still as wide to not show any scrollbars, because this seems to be the size the widget keeps stuck on when the outer widget starts showing scrollbars.

If this was a regular `QScrollArea`, I'd try to use `QScrollArea::widget()->size()` but `QTreeWidget` does not provide the `widget` function that allows obtaining a handle to the contained widget.

Therefore the questions is: How can I compute/get the width (size) of a `QTreeWidget` ignoring the fact that the widget may only be shown partially due to scrollbars being active.

Note: I want to stress that I do NOT want to get the width of the viewport minus the scrollbar's width (on that topic there are numerous questions here on SO).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming one is dealing with a "regular" tree widget (header oriented horizontally), one can get the width of the tree's content irrespective of whether or not a horizontal scrollbar is being shown by using

```
const int width = myTreeWidget->header()->length();
```

Refs:

- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#length